# Is it possible to create nested tsql function for changing schema?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, nested

I want to create a user defined function that my customer can run on a database with their own schema (it will not be dbo always), for example:

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'IsTest', N'FN') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION IsTest;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION IsTest (@Date datetime)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
 RETURN IsOcToday(@Date) -- *** This function is nested
END
```

and

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'IsOcToday', N'FN') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION IsOcToday;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION IsOcToday (@Date datetime)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
 IF
 (
 (@Date >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) 
 AND 
 (@Date < DATEADD(DAY,1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)))
 )
    RETURN 1
RETURN 0
END
```

I understand that you need two parts when calling the UDF but is there any way to avoid it or dynamically assign it.

When calling the top level function I can find the schema and append it but I cannot do that with the nested function.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do.

Comment: One solution is to create a schema (ex. `Common`) that will include  `IsOcToday` function. Then, every customer could call this function (ex. `SELECT Common.IsOcToday()`).

Comment: One issue with that could be I need to provide "grant schema" permission to to user, which will defeat the purpose of the ability for the users to install the function when they do not have the dbo permission.

Comment: you may be able to use a `synonym` to redirect to the nested function (depending on SQL Server version) - but I think it would have the same problem with permissions

Answer (score 1):

It is only scalar valued functions that need the schema prefix.

Rewrite `IsOcToday` to be a table valued function instead.

```
CREATE FUNCTION IsOcToday (@Date datetime)
RETURNS @T TABLE(Ret int)
AS
BEGIN
  IF @Date >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AND 
     @Date < DATEADD(DAY,1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @T VALUES(1)
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @T VALUES(0)
  END
  RETURN
END
```

And change how you use it in `IsTest`.

```
CREATE FUNCTION IsTest (@Date datetime)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT Ret FROM IsOcToday(@Date))
END
```

If you can rewrite your function to be an inline scalar function that is almost always the better choice. In your case the function would look like this instead.

```
CREATE FUNCTION IsOcToday (@Date datetime)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
(
  SELECT CASE WHEN @Date >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AND 
                   @Date < DATEADD(DAY,1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
           THEN 1
           ELSE 0
         END  AS Ret
)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ce038/1)

Comment: isn't there a performance penalty for using tables for data manipulation function?

Comment: @Samuel as a rule of thumb you can say that inline table valued functions are good for performance compared to the other two that are bad and even really really bad depending on how you use them. You have to test to know for sure how it is in your case.

Comment: If you could show some code where you actually use `IsOcToday` I can also have something to test on and show you how your function will work and what alternatives there are and how that work.